# Is there a way to be adviced which site to ask?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button

Here, you can search for a site web with a specific word *that is in the name of the website*.

[image: Search menu]

What I'm asking for is a way to type "Apache server configuration" and then to see which sites matches the closest with those keywords.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/search?q=Apache+server+configuration

Answer (score 3):

Currently this is not possible. You can search the site switcher only by site's name and it's description. So you need to search by site's purpose to find the correct site.

E.g. To find site related to video games you may search like "game" or "video" which will suggest you [Arqade.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).

Since your example is related to Server you could search by "server".

The main reason for not implementing such feature (search by a specific topic) is (IMO) there are lots of topics for a single site which raise everyday. So it's not possible to implement it.

However, if you don't find any site for your question, just ask here a question tagged with [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation). You may get your answer soon.

Comment: This is not possible. That's why it's a feature request... and you're right: there are lots of topics for a single site which raise everyday. But how about this: bring only the most relevant ones? Like the 3 websites matching the most?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding **Apache server configuration** you have to ask in https://serverfault.com/ site. If your question is about Stack Exchange search functionality then make it clear, because currently unclear to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm not asking for those specifics words, I'm asking for a feature that doesn't seem to be implemented yet... unless I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

To answer your current question according to your description (not by answering your example):

- No, it is not possible that way.
- If you want to know which site you should use, ask a question here with the tag [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation).

An automated system to suggest the right site is

- hard to implement
- has to adjusted regulary (sometimes the scope of a site changes)
- At least I don't know how it could work.

So better leave it the current way: ask on [Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)